# C++ Threading and string help please

Tags: c++, multithreading

I am loosing my mind and new to C++ I know C# where I know that it is as simple as

```
var cat = "cat";
dvar(0,0, "hi" +cat+ "hi");
```

My issue here is I am developing a game and need to put a string into a function call like so:

```
string host = "HIST";
dvar(0,0, "s \"test" + host.c_str() + "connection\"");
```

Also about the threading I am going nuts because my game I can only call in one function at a time but I have a function that is on scree instructions that has a constant while loop so it's to busy handing that looping thread for me to activate any other functions via buttons.

Comment: You really need to take a step back. You apparently cannot handle the most simple C++ code and talk about threading later. This wont go well.

Comment: Let your mind loose! That's a good mental state for any developer. Or, as an int said to an Integer, it's important to think outside the box.

Comment: @pmr Indeed. And above all, that should really be to separate questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should do call the function without the `c_str()` in order to use the non-member string concatenation function.

```
dvar(0,0, ("s \"test" + host + "connection\"").c_str());
```

Since `host` is a `std::string` type the `+` operator will result in calling the non-member function `operator+` for `std::string`.

E.g. `host + "connection"` will result in calling the following function, where `"connection"` is implicitly converted into a `std::string`:

```
std::string operator+(const std::string& lhs, std::string&& rhs);
```

However, if you would do `host.c_str() + "connection"`, the compiler would be looking for a function that looks like:

```
??? operator+(const char* lhs, const char* rhs);
```

Which doesn't exist in the standard library.

Comment: Not sure of a thing you said, but it works :) all I had to do was add the .c_str()); at the end of the function, thanks man! good work god damn genius. 

Do you know much about threading so that I can finish this? it's actually a DLL for the game modern warfare two and I'm on a timescale here haha and being paid for this O.o cause not many people know how to edit the MW2 files.

Comment: Well, I don't rly see what your question is regarding threading. I would suggestion your create a new question and explain your problem.

Answer (score 0):

The expression:

```
"s \"test" + host.c_str() + "connection\"
```

will try to add pointers to `char`. This cannot work. You might be
looking for a string class?

```
std::string host = "bar";
// this is quite inefficient
func("foo" + host + "baz");
// this is somewhat better
std::string x = "foo";
x.append(host);
x.append("baz");
func(x);
```

Comment: In C++11 the first one, i.e. func("foo" + host + "baz") would be preferable.

Comment: @ronag True. I didn't consider that `operator+` would support rvalues.